# Vector valued polynomial composition; Computational complexity

Tags: polynomials, computational-complexity, fast-fourier-transform

Let 
$$P:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$$
be a vector valued polynomial. What is the computational complexity of the composition of two such polynomial? Can the Fast Fourier Transform be employed on vector valued polynomial?

Composition of single valued polynomials can be computed using FFT, as by [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64391/computation-for-composition-of-polynomials) answer.

Comment: I am not sure that you can employ fft to efficiently compute the composition of scalar polynomials.

Comment: Added an edit regarding your comment.

Comment: I am not sure that the same method applies to composition with non linear polynomial...

Comment: I see. Might you point me in the correct direction, I have been googling all day to no awail...

Comment: Why do you think it is possible? Is it an assignment? I have never heard of it (though that means nothing).

Comment: No, not an assignment, I am an amateur, I do some thinking as a hobby, mostly employing this site for educational guidance. I was thinking about general polynomials represented as elements of the tensor product of the vector space with the tensor algebra of its dual, V\otimes S(V^*). As complexity of contraction increases with order, I started thinking if one can optimize these contractions in some way. Any guidance would be welcomed

Comment: hm... vector valued polynomials are fundamentally different than scalar valued ones. I wouldn't expect too much.

Comment: So I should rather remove myself from FFT, and looking into general methods for tensor algebra/contraction optimization? I found this paper on the subject http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2442861

Comment: yes (just my intuition).